# notifyDataSetChange() not updating DataGrid() via ArrayAdapter()

Tags: android, datagrid, android-arrayadapter

In the code below have a variable of type List '<'String'>' named 'stringList' which is bound to a GridView view via and ArrayAdapter. The code below runs a for loop which creates a string and adds it to 'stringList'. As can be seen in the LogCat output the ArrayAdapter's getView() function is triggered when the OnCreate() sub routine concludes and the GridView is populated. What I want is for the GridView to populate one item at a time as each iteration of the for loop is run.

My research indicated that notifyDataSetObersver() function is the correct tool for accomplishing this. Although notifyDataSetObersver() is triggering in each iteration of the for loop it is not clear that it's doing anything, and my GridView is still getting populated after the onCreate() sub routine concludes.

If anyone has any suggestions I would be very appreciative.

*Please not the code below (as indicated in comments) relies on a the two layout resources titled "main" and "data_grid" pasted below the code.

**Code:**

```
package com.arrayadapterupdate2;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main extends Activity {

    LinearLayout mainLinearLayout;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    GridArrayAdapter gridAdapter;
    GridView gridView;
    List<String> stringList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.main);
        stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        //The Resource 'mainLinearLayout' is a Linear Layout in the set content view 'main'
        mainLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.mainLinearLayout);
        //The Resource 'grid_view' is a layout containing an empty gridview
        gridView = (GridView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_view,null);
        gridAdapter = new GridArrayAdapter(this, stringList, R.layout.grid_view);
        gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);
        System.out.println("main triggered");
        stringList.clear();
        int i;
        int j =10;
            for (i=0;i<=j-1;i=i+1){
            System.out.println("Loop: "+i);
            String string;
            String addedString = "String "+i;
            stringList.add(addedString); 
            gridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
         mainLinearLayout.addView(gridView);
    }


public class GridArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter implements OnClickListener {

    private Context context;
    private List<String> stringList;

    public GridArrayAdapter(Context context, List<String> stringList, int id) {
        super(context, id, stringList);
        this.context = context;
        this.stringList = stringList;

    }   
@Override

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
         System.out.println("Get View Triggered "+ position);
         String string = stringList.get(position);
         LinearLayout gridViewElement = new LinearLayout(context);
         TextView textView = new TextView(context);
         textView.setText(string);
         gridViewElement.addView(textView);
        if (convertView == null) { 
            convertView = (View)gridViewElement;
        }  
        return convertView;
    }

@Override 

public void notifyDataSetChanged(){

System.out.println("Notify Data Set Changed Triggered");
}

@Override 

public int getCount() {

    return stringList.size();
}

@Override 

public Object getItem(int position) {

    return stringList.get(position);
}

@Override 

public long getItemId(int position) {

    return position;
}

@Override

public void onClick(View arg0) {

}
}

}
```

**Portion of LogCat Output:**

08-24 20:10:09.395: INFO/System.out(223): main triggered

08-24 20:10:09.395: INFO/System.out(223): Loop: 0

08-24 20:10:09.395: INFO/System.out(223): Notify Data Set Changed Triggered

08-24 20:10:09.395: INFO/System.out(223): Loop: 1

08-24 20:10:09.395: INFO/System.out(223): Notify Data Set Changed Triggered

08-24 20:10:09.395: INFO/System.out(223): Loop: 2

08-24 20:10:09.395: INFO/System.out(223): Notify Data Set Changed Triggered

08-24 20:10:09.395: INFO/System.out(223): Loop: 3

08-24 20:10:09.405: INFO/System.out(223): Notify Data Set Changed Triggered

08-24 20:10:09.405: INFO/System.out(223): Loop: 4

08-24 20:10:09.405: INFO/System.out(223): Notify Data Set Changed Triggered

08-24 20:10:09.405: INFO/System.out(223): Loop: 5

08-24 20:10:09.405: INFO/System.out(223): Notify Data Set Changed Triggered

08-24 20:10:09.405: INFO/System.out(223): Loop: 6

08-24 20:10:09.405: INFO/System.out(223): Notify Data Set Changed Triggered

08-24 20:10:09.405: INFO/System.out(223): Loop: 7

08-24 20:10:09.405: INFO/System.out(223): Notify Data Set Changed Triggered

08-24 20:10:09.405: INFO/System.out(223): Loop: 8

08-24 20:10:09.405: INFO/System.out(223): Notify Data Set Changed Triggered

08-24 20:10:09.405: INFO/System.out(223): Loop: 9

08-24 20:10:09.405: INFO/System.out(223): Notify Data Set Changed Triggered

08-24 20:10:09.415: INFO/System.out(223): On Create Concluded

08-24 20:10:09.445: INFO/System.out(223): Get View Triggered 0

08-24 20:10:09.495: INFO/System.out(223): Get View Triggered 0

08-24 20:10:09.515: INFO/System.out(223): Get View Triggered 1

08-24 20:10:09.515: INFO/System.out(223): Get View Triggered 2

08-24 20:10:09.525: INFO/System.out(223): Get View Triggered 3

08-24 20:10:09.525: INFO/System.out(223): Get View Triggered 4

08-24 20:10:09.525: INFO/System.out(223): Get View Triggered 5

08-24 20:10:09.537: INFO/System.out(223): Get View Triggered 6

08-24 20:10:09.537: INFO/System.out(223): Get View Triggered 7

08-24 20:10:09.545: INFO/System.out(223): Get View Triggered 8

08-24 20:10:09.545: INFO/System.out(223): Get View Triggered 9

08-24 20:10:09.676: INFO/ActivityManager(51): Displayed activity

com.arrayadapterupdate2/.Main: 972 ms (total 972 ms)

---

Hey Kerubu below is my attempt at implimenting your suggestion along with a portion of the LogCat output. As you can see from the LogCat although notifyDataSetChanged() is being called getView() is neither being called by notifyDataSetChanged() or by the conclusion of the onCreate() sub routine.

I greatly appreciate all your help, and any further advice would be welcome.

Code:

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    LinearLayout mainLinearLayout;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    GridView gridView;
    List<String> stringList;
    Handler androidHandler;
    private GuiThreadMessageHandler guiThreadMsgHandler;
    private GridArrayAdapter gridAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            System.out.println("On Create Started");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        //The Resource 'mainLinearLayout' is a Linear Layout in the set content view 'main'
        mainLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.mainLinearLayout);
        //The Resource 'grid_view' is a layout containing an empty gridview
        gridView = (GridView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_view,null);
        gridAdapter = new GridArrayAdapter(this, stringList, R.layout.grid_view);
        gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);
        stringList.clear();
        guiThreadMsgHandler = new GuiThreadMessageHandler();
        new GridArrayPopulator().execute();
        mainLinearLayout.addView(gridView);
        System.out.println("On Create Concluded");
    }

    private class GridArrayPopulator extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params){
            /* Here do your loop and notify the Gui thread */
            int i;
            int j =10;
            Message msg;
            String addedString;
            for (i=0;i<=j-1;i=i+1){
                System.out.println("loop: "+i);
                addedString = "String "+i;
                stringList.add(addedString); 
                msg = Message.obtain(guiThreadMsgHandler);
                msg.sendToTarget();
        }
            return null;
  }
    }


public class GuiThreadMessageHandler extends Handler {
 public void handleMessage(Message m){
     System.out.println("Notify Data Set Changed Triggered ");
     gridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}

public class GridArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter implements OnClickListener {

    private Context context;
    private List<String> stringList;

    public GridArrayAdapter(Context context, List<String> stringList, int id) {
        super(context, id, stringList);
        this.context = context;
        this.stringList = stringList;

    }   
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
         System.out.println("Get View Triggered "+ position);
         String string = stringList.get(position);
         LinearLayout gridViewElement = new LinearLayout(context);
         TextView textView = new TextView(context);
         textView.setText(string);
         gridViewElement.addView(textView);
        if (convertView == null) { 
            convertView = (View)gridViewElement;
        }  
        return convertView;
    }

@Override 
public void notifyDataSetChanged(){
System.out.println("Notify Data Set Changed Triggered");
}

@Override 
public int getCount() {
    return stringList.size();
}

@Override 
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return stringList.get(position);
}

@Override 
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
}
}
}
```

LogCat:

```
08-25 17:41:12.872: INFO/System.out(705): On Create Started
08-25 17:41:12.972: INFO/System.out(705): On Create Concluded
08-25 17:41:13.111: WARN/IInputConnectionWrapper(31516): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
08-25 17:41:13.191: INFO/ActivityManager(1357): Displayed activity com.arrayadapterupdate2/.Main: 934 ms (total 934 ms)
08-25 17:41:13.261: DEBUG/vending(1482): [2073] LocalAssetCache.updateOnePackage(): No local info for com.arrayadapterupdate2
08-25 17:41:13.261: INFO/System.out(705): loop: 0
08-25 17:41:13.261: INFO/ActivityManager(1357): Stopping service: com.android.vending/.util.WorkService
08-25 17:41:13.321: INFO/System.out(705): Notify Data Set Changed Triggered 
08-25 17:41:13.321: INFO/System.out(705): Notify Data Set Changed Triggered
08-25 17:41:13.351: INFO/System.out(705): loop: 1
08-25 17:41:13.351: INFO/System.out(705): Notify Data Set Changed Triggered 
08-25 17:41:13.351: INFO/System.out(705): Notify Data Set Changed Triggered
08-25 17:41:13.351: INFO/System.out(705): loop: 2
08-25 17:41:13.361: INFO/System.out(705): Notify Data Set Changed Triggered 
08-25 17:41:13.361: INFO/System.out(705): Notify Data Set Changed Triggered
08-25 17:41:13.361: INFO/System.out(705): loop: 3
08-25 17:41:13.391: INFO/System.out(705): Notify Data Set Changed Triggered 
08-25 17:41:13.391: INFO/System.out(705): Notify Data Set Changed Triggered
08-25 17:41:13.391: INFO/System.out(705): loop: 4
08-25 17:41:13.391: INFO/System.out(705): Notify Data Set Changed Triggered 
08-25 17:41:13.391: INFO/System.out(705): Notify Data Set Changed Triggered
08-25 17:41:13.401: INFO/System.out(705): loop: 5
08-25 17:41:13.422: INFO/System.out(705): Notify Data Set Changed Triggered 
08-25 17:41:13.422: INFO/System.out(705): Notify Data Set Changed Triggered
08-25 17:41:13.422: INFO/System.out(705): loop: 6
08-25 17:41:13.441: INFO/System.out(705): Notify Data Set Changed Triggered 
08-25 17:41:13.441: INFO/System.out(705): Notify Data Set Changed Triggered
08-25 17:41:13.441: INFO/System.out(705): loop: 7
08-25 17:41:13.462: INFO/System.out(705): Notify Data Set Changed Triggered 
08-25 17:41:13.462: INFO/System.out(705): Notify Data Set Changed Triggered
08-25 17:41:13.462: INFO/System.out(705): loop: 8
08-25 17:41:13.462: INFO/System.out(705): Notify Data Set Changed Triggered 
08-25 17:41:13.462: INFO/System.out(705): Notify Data Set Changed Triggered
08-25 17:41:13.462: INFO/System.out(705): loop: 9
08-25 17:41:13.471: INFO/System.out(705): Notify Data Set Changed Triggered 
08-25 17:41:13.471: INFO/System.out(705): Notify Data Set Changed Triggered
```

Comment: Why adding "one string at a time"? What are you trying to achieve? In terms of results or effect, this is quite unclear.

Comment: The program I'm implementing this in populates the GridView with downloaded information parsed from a JSON document. This process is slow so I feel it would be satisfying for the user to see the information appear one item at a time as the JSON is parsed.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following might explain what is happening:

onCreate() runs in the GUI thread. You're looping in onCreate() and in the loop you are adding the data to the GridView. by doing this you are essentially hogging the GUI thread until you complete your loop. Android therefore does not get chance to respond to your calls to notifyDataSetChanged() i.e. it cannot 'paint' to the screen because you are hogging the GUI thread with your loop.

As a suggestion, I would create a new thread and put your loop in there and also call notifyDataSetchanged() from there also (though please check Android docs that this method can be safely called from a thread other than the GUI. 
To make things easy, android has the [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) class to help with thread creation etc.

**Edit**
I just had a look at some code where I was trying to do a similar thing as you. It appears that calling notifyDataSetchanged() might only be allowed from the GUI thread. To get round this, I created a Message Handler in the GUI thread which would call notifyDataSetchanged(). This Message handler would be notified from other threads by sending it a Message.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I added the code below to the class "Main" and replaced "gridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()" with "notifyAdapter()" in the for loop. The only difference in the LogCat output is that notifyDataSetChanged() is getting triggered a bunch of times after onCreate() concludes instead of once per loop. But getView() is still only triggering after onCreate() conlcudes. Have I implemented your suggestion properly?

Comment: public void notifyAdapter() {                                         

        Thread t = new Thread() {                                     

            public void run() {                                       
                    messageHandler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(messageHandler,  null)); 
                }  
        };           
        t.start();       
    }
    
    private Handler messageHandler = new Handler() {
     @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
     gridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };

Comment: P.S. Sorry about the crummy looking code above I'm trying to figure         out how to do line breaks right now.

Comment: See my example code below. Note I have not checked it for errors, typos etc but it givs you the outline of what I believe you need to do.

Comment: Are you calling the super class method notifyDataSetChaged?

Comment: I'm not sure what that entails. I thought super class methods were only applicable to inherited classes not overridden methods. Would you kindly go into a little more detail. Also the only place I could find a yeild() function was if I use a looper. Is this right? Thanks again for your help I appreciate it very much.

Comment: You've created a subclass of ArrayAdapter. You've also overridden the notifyDataSetchanged() method but because you overridden this method AND have NOT called the superclass method of the same name, you ArrayAdapter will NEVER call its containing window. I assume your notifyDataSetChanged() method is being called from your log file, but to make sure you should change the text string to something UNIQUE to that method.

Comment: To call the superclass method it is super.onDataSetChanged(); Also I have made other comments for you but they seem to be getting deleted by someone.

Answer (score 0):

This is roughly what I think you should do. Please note I have not included code for setting up the GridArray but it's the same as what you quoted in your original post anyway.

```
    public class YourActivity extends Activity {
        private GuiThreadMessageHandler guiThreadMsgHandler;
        private GridArrayAdapter gridAdapter;

        onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                guiThreadMsgHandler = new GuiThreadMessageHandler();
                new GridArrayPopulator().execute();
        }

        private class GridArrayPopulator extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

               @Override
               protected Void doInBackground(Void.. params){
                   /* Here do your loop and notify the Gui thread */
                    int i;
                    int j =10;
                    Message msg;
                    String addedString;
                    for (i=0;i<=j-1;i=i+1){
                        //System.out.println("Loop: "+i);
                        //String string;
                        addedString = "String "+i;
                        stringList.add(addedString); 
                        msg = Message.obtain(guiThreadMsgHandler);
                        msg.sendToTarget()
               }
         }

    }

public class GuiThreadMessageHandler extends Handler {
        public void handleMessage(Message m){
            gridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Comment: Kerubu, thank you for the code. Unfortunately my implementation of it isn't solving the problem. I've pasted my code in the answer above. If you have time to take a look and make any suggestions I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Thank you for following up. I have taken a couple tries at implementing your suggestions, but unfortunately it is still is not working. Any further suggestions are appreciated,